# Why getting private member variables as null, even after setting them with values?

Tags: java, oop

In my application, I am mimicking a class which is written as below. But when I print the private member variables str1 and str2, even after setting them through some private method are coming out as null. I can't understand the Java OO principle here.

```
public class Test {
    private String str1;
    private String str2;

    public Test() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Test();
        t.doSomeThing();
    }

    private void setProperties() {
        str1 = "String One";
        str2 = "String Two";
        System.out.println("str1=" + str1 + ",str2=" + str2);
    }

    public void doSomeThing() {
        Test t = new Test();
        t.setProperties();
        System.out.println("str1=" + str1 + ",str2=" + str2);
    }
}
```

The out put I am getting is like..

```
str1=String One,str2=String Two
str1=null,str2=null
```

Comment: I found the solution, but could not understand why it is working !! Here it is 
```public class Test {
 private static String str1;
 private static String str2;
 // private static Test t = null;

 public Test() {
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Test t = new Test();
  t.doSomeThing();
 }

 private static void setProperties() {
  str1 = "String One";
  str2 = "String Two";
  System.out.println("str1=" + str1 + ",str2=" + str2);
 }

 public void doSomeThing() {
  Test.setProperties();
  System.out.println("str1=" + str1 + ",str2=" + str2);
 }
}  ```

Comment: Basically I made the two private variables str1, str2 and the method setProperties() as static. I don't understand why it made to work !!??

Comment: You should read the basics of Java, what means static and how class instantiation works.

Comment: You are calling `new Test()` twice--think about that.

Answer (score 1):

In your `doSomething` method you are creating a new instance of class `Test` on which you call `setProperties` instead of calling it on `this` like:

```java
public void doSomeThing() {
  this.setProperties();
  System.out.println("str1=" + str1 + ",str2=" + str2);
}
```

When calling a non static method on an instance of a class, you can refer to the "current" instance methods or attributes by using `this.xxx` or even just `xxx` if there is no ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

In

```java
    public void doSomeThing() {
        Test t = new Test();
        t.setProperties();
        System.out.println("str1=" + str1 + ",str2=" + str2);
    }
```

You are creating a new instance of Test and are setting the values of the newly created object, but in the `System.out` you are outputting the values of `this` (the object the doSomething method is called upon.

To get the output you expect, you would need to do:

```java
    public void doSomeThing() {
        setProperties(); //or more formallly this.setProperties();
        System.out.println("str1=" + str1 + ",str2=" + str2);
    }
```

This way the str1 and str2 of your current object is set.

Answer (score 1):

When you are calling **t.doSomeThing()** in **main()**, it takes you to the **doSomeThing()** function, there you are creating another **instance**(object) of class **Test** with **same name t.** BUT according to OOP concept it is **another** instance as **constructor** was called **again**.So it will have its own fields(str1 str2). Now you are calling t.setProperties(), it is using newly created object **t**(let's say, t1) and fills its fields, leaving the old object **t** fields **null**.

You can **fill the old object value** by calling **setProperties()**, **before** making new object , by making changes to doSomeThing() as,

```
public void doSomeThing() {
    System.out.println("Value of first t:");
    this.setProperties();         //or setProperties() or t.setProperties()   
    System.out.println("str1=" + str1 + ",str2=" + str2);
    Test t = new Test();
    System.out.println("Value of second t:");
    this.setProperties();
    System.out.println("str1=" + str1 + ",str2=" + str2);
}
```

**this** operator points towards the current instance of the class, just a good habit.
Here, *first* **setProperties()** will set value for **old** object whereas *second* **setProprties()** will set values for **newly** created object.The output will be,

```
Value of first t:
str1=String One,str2=String Two
str1=String One,str2=String Two
Value of second t:
str1=String One,str2=String Two
str1=String One,str2=String Two
```

Answer (score 0):

With the input from many experts, I could able to rectify the mistake with out declaring the fields, or any method static.

```
public class Test {
private String str1;
private String str2;

// private static Test t = null;

public Test() {
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test t = new Test();
    t.doSomeThing();
}

private void setProperties() {
    str1 = "String One";
    str2 = "String Two";
    System.out.println("str1=" + str1 + ",str2=" + str2);
}

public void doSomeThing() {
    this.setProperties();
    System.out.println("str1=" + str1 + ",str2=" + str2);
}
```

}